# proving the validity

Tags: logic, quantifiers, satisfiability

I need to prove the validity of the formula:

$Q= \forall x \forall y \forall v \ F(x,y,f(x,y),v, g(x,y,v)) \rightarrow \forall x \forall y \exists z \forall v \exists u \ F(x,y,z,v,u)$

I thought the best way to do this is by proving that $\neg Q$ is unsatisfiable and I tried the Tableaux Method but I did not know what I should do with the $f$ and $g$ so I couldn't reach a closed tableau

I would appreciate some pointers or suggestions on how to prove the validity of $Q$ or maybe what I'm doing wrong in the tableau

Comment: If I remember my tableau, you get $\forall x,y,z F(...)$ (the antecedent) and $\neg \forall x,y \exists z ...$ (the negation the of consequent). You should have a rule that allows you to conclude $\neg \exists z \forall v \exists u F(a,b,z,v,u)$ for some $a,b$. To reduce $\neg\exists z$ we need something to apply it to. The terms we have lying around are those involving $a,b,f,g$. To line up with the antecedent (which we are trying to contradict) instantiate $f(a,b)$ for $z$. This should get you going.

Comment: you mean that I can for example expand this $$\neg \exists z \forall v \exists u \ F(a.b,z,v,u)$$ 

to this:

$$\neg \forall v \exists u \ F(a.b,f(a,b),v,u)$$

Comment: Your proof system should be able to allow that inference (possibly in multiple steps). It is clearly a valid inference, as, if there is no $z$ satisfying the rest, then, in particuar $z = f(a,b)$ does not satisfy the rest.

Comment: that does makes sense, thanks, I'll see what I can do. ....

by the way I'll be happy to accept your comment as an answer if you re-post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember my tableaus, you get $\forall x,y,zF(\ldots)$ (the antecedent) and $\neg\forall x,y\exists z\ldots$ (the negation the of consequent).

You should have a rule that allows you to conclude 
$$¬∃z∀v∃uF(a,b,z,v,u)$$
for some $a,b$. To reduce $¬∃z$ we need something to apply it to. The terms we have lying around are those involving $a,b,f,g$. To line up with the antecedent (which we are trying to contradict) instantiate $f(a,b)$ for $z$. This should get you going.